# tense question about 'Would it be okay if~' phrase

Tags: tense

I found some sentences that used 'would it be okay if~?'phrase.
But some of them used past tense with above phrase, but others used present tense with that.

> Would it be possible if I talked to him before he left?
>   Would it be possible if I talk to him before he leaves?

Is there any difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the setup from

> **Would it be okay if**

to

> **Would it be possible if**

you've changed your question.

Both of these have a very different meanings than you other possible sentences

> **Would it be possible if** I talked to him before he left?
>   **Would it be possible if** I talk to him before he leaves?

since they ask about the possibility of *something else*. However, both of these are correct

> **Would it be okay if** I talked to him before he left?
>   **Would it be okay if** I talk to him before he leaves?

and talk about the possibility of speaking to the person.
There is no difference between the last two sentences.